# What does "Unable to find storage information for property" mean when using DynamoDB?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm running a scan using the .NET SDK for AWS DynamoDB.  I'm doing this:

```
var result = context.Scan<Table>(new[] { new ScanCondition("AttributeName", ScanOperator.Equal, variable) }
```

This throws the exception

> "Unable to find storage information for property [AttributeName]"

The attribute `AttributeName` is a non-indexed attribute that currently has mostly no value in it (it's a new attribute I added recently).

I googled the error & all I came up with was the [sdk source code](https://github.com/kenstone/aws-sdk-for-net/blob/master/Amazon.DynamoDB/DataModel/InternalModel.cs#L81), which I could dive into, and I will if noone here can enlighten me.

Answer (score 10):

This got me too, sharing my findings hoping it could help someone, I am using C# Object persistent model.

Column names in DynamoDb are in Camel case. C# class properties are not.

```
[DynamoDBProperty("artist")]
    [DynamoDBHashKey]
    public string Artist { get; set; }

    [DynamoDBProperty("songTitle")]
    [DynamoDBRangeKey]
    public string SongTitle { get; set; }
```

Therefore following throws the error,

```
scanConditions.Add(new ScanCondition("songTitle", ScanOperator.BeginsWith, searchReq.SongTitle));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchReq.Difficulty))
```

To fix,

```
scanConditions.Add(new ScanCondition("SongTitle", ScanOperator.BeginsWith, searchReq.SongTitle));
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchReq.Difficulty))
```

Comment: Wow. I'm new to DynamoDB + DynamoDBContext in C#. I was stuck for a while here, not noticing the case-sensitivity. Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 4):

The `DynamoDBContext.Scan<T>()` method only accepts names of public properties of the class `T` that is mapped to that table using the `[DynamoDBTable()]` attribute. `Scan<T>` will not recognize unmapped attributes in the table.

That exception will be thrown if the class `T` either doesn't have a **public** property of that name, or if the property is explicitly marked `[DynamoDBIgnore]`.

If you need to scan the table for table attributes that are not modeled, you can use the low-level API provided by `AmazonDynamoDBClient.Scan()`, but it won't return objects of type T.

Comment: The property was modeled.  It just didn't have a lot of data in it. I have a sneaking suspicion that this was the problem as the the low-level API could scan it just fine.  I think the high level API was expecting data

Comment: That error is thown by the code that is inspecting the model, not the data, so it would be confusing if it were being triggered by some property of the data. Is it possible that the model class is out of date soemhow? Is it in a different DLL perhaps? Project needs a clean/rebuild in VS?

Comment: No, it's all up to date. Tried a clean & it still didn't work.

Comment: Can you provide the complete code for the modeled class you are using?

Answer (score 1):

your statement is:

```
var result = context.Scan<Table>(new[] { new ScanCondition("AttributeName", ScanOperator.Equal, variable) }
```

As per DynamoDB documentation, you need to pass "propertyName" in place of "AttributeName".

DynamoDB documentation says:

```
public ScanCondition(
string propertyName,
ScanOperator op,
params Object[] values)
```

Refer: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_DynamoDB_DataModel_ScanCondition__ctor.htm